# Write a formal proof that proves $ (A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B') = A $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Write a formal proof that proves $ (A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B') = A $

Our professor showed us the following proof:

1. $\forall x \in (A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B')$
2. $\text{----}$Suppose $ x\in B$
3. $\text{----}$Then $ x\in A \cap B$
4. $\text{----}$So $ x\in A $
5. $\text{----}$Suppose $ x\in B'$
6. $\text{----}$Then $ x\in A \cap B'$
7. $\text{----}$So $ x\in A $
8. Since $ x\in B$ or $ x\in B'$, $x \in A$

I tried understanding this proof several times and can't understand the jump between step 2 and 3 and between 5 and 6. Here are my explanations for the other steps:

1. $\forall x \in (A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B')$ (Assumption)
2. $\text{----}$Suppose $ x\in B$ (Assumption)
3. $\text{----}$Then $ x\in A \cap B$ (????)
4. $\text{----}$So $ x\in A $ (Simplification)
5. $\text{----}$Suppose $ x\in B'$ (Assumption)
6. $\text{----}$Then $ x\in A \cap B'$ (????)
7. $\text{----}$So $ x\in A $ (Simplification)
8. Since $ x\in B$ or $ x\in B'$, $x \in A$ (Resolution)

I just do not understand how you can conclude that $x$ is in $A\cap B$ if it's in $B$

Comment: Technically, a true formal proof would show that $LHS \subseteq RHS$ and $RHS \subseteq LHS$. Your professor appears to be implying that $x$ is a member of the left hand side in step 1. In that case, saying step 2 would imply step 3

Comment: @WaveX ... or the professor gave the two parts *but* bar9833625 muddled them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor's proof is indeed not very clear, and also as written it only shows $(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')\subseteq A$. Before answering your question, let me write how I would write the proof of that inclusions:

1. Let $x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')$.
2. Suppose $x\in A\cap B$.
3. Then $x\in A$.
4. Suppose $x\in A\cap B'$.
5. Then $x\in A$.
6. Since $x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')$ then $x\in A$.

Now for your question: I think the only way you can conclude is that from $1$ you know either $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A\cap B'$ or both. Now if $x\in B$ you know that $x\notin B'$ hence $x\notin A\cap B'$, so only the alternative $x\in A\cap B$ remains. Similarly, if $x\in B'$ then $x\notin B$, and only the alternative $x\in A\cap B'$ remains.

Let me finally emphasize that to prove the equality, you also have to show that reverse inclusion $A\subseteq(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')$. In this case the argument of your professor applies better (perhaps he has confused the argument when writing the proof):

1. Let $x\in A$.
2. Suppose that $x\in B$.
3. Then $x\in A\cap B$.
4. Suppose that $x\in B'$.
5. Then $x\in A\cap B'$.
6. Since either $x\in B$ or $x\in B'$, it follows that $x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the steps skipped is some form of a proof by contradiction.

After step 2, suppose instead that $x \in A \cap B'$.

Then $x \in B'$, which contradicts $x \in B$.

Hence $x \notin A \cap B'$.

Since $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B')$, which means that $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in A \cap B'$, by *Disjunctive Syllogism*, we must arrive at $x \in (A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B')$, we have that $x \in A \cap B $ or $ x \in A \cap B'$. Thus, in either case $x \in A$. Adding the assumption from line 2, that $x \in B$, we obtain line 3, which says that $x \in A \cap B$.

Comment: Or another way to see it is by noting that $x \in B \implies x \notin B' \implies x \notin A \cap B' $. But $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B')$ so $x \in A \cap B$

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this proof.  First derive $x\in (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{\small\complement})$ under the assumption of $x\in A$.  The second does the converse, and makes use of the Law of Excluded Middle to note that either $x\in B$ or it is not.

Both parts have a Proof by Cases structure, where you derive the same consequent to assuming either case of a union.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{\boxed x}{\fitch{x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{\small\complement})\qquad\text{Supposition}}{\fitch{x\in (A\cap B)\qquad\text{Supposition}}{x\in A\qquad\text{Simplification}}\\\fitch{x\in (A\cap B^{\small\complement})\qquad\text{Supposition}}{x\in A\qquad\text{Simplification}}\\x\in A\qquad\text{Proof by Cases}}\\[2ex]\fitch{x\in A\qquad\text{Supposition}}{x\in B\cup B^{\small\complement}\qquad\textsf{(LEM)}\\\fitch{x\in B\qquad\text{Supposition}}{x\in A\cap B\qquad\text{Conjunction}\\x\in((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{\small\complement}))\qquad\text{Addition}}\\\fitch{x\in B^{\small\complement}\qquad\text{Supposition}}{x\in A\cap B^{\small\complement}\qquad\text{Conjunction}\\x\in((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{\small\complement}))\qquad\text{Addition}}\\x\in((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{\small\complement}))\qquad\text{Proof by Cases}}\\[2ex]x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{\small\complement}))\qquad\text{Biconditional Proofs}}\\[2ex]A = ((A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{\small\complement}))\qquad\text{Definition of Set Equality}}$$

Comment: This proof is great! One question, what does the x in the box mean?

Comment: @bar9833625 It is a local variable declaration.  "Let $x$ be an arbitrary variable."

Answer (score 0):

One step is missing.

1.5. If $x$ is as in 1 then it is either in $A\cap B$ or in $A\cap B^c$ and these two sets a disjoint.

In 2 you need to refer to 1.5

In 5 you need to refer to 1.5

You also need to prove the opposite inclusion $ A\subseteq...$. For this you assume $x\in A$ and then use step 6.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma 1**. If $\mathcal{P}$, $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are propositions, then:

$$\mathcal{P}\vee (\mathcal{Q}\wedge \mathcal{R})= (\mathcal{P}\vee \mathcal{Q})\wedge (\mathcal{P}\vee \mathcal{R}) \tag 1$$

*Proof*. By showing that the truth tables of the LHS and RHS of $(1)$ are equal for the same entries of $\mathcal{P}$, $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{R}$. $\space\Box$

By the Lemma 1 (precisely at $(*)$ steps):

\begin{alignat}{1}
(A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B') &= \{x\mid (x\in A\wedge x\in B) \vee (x\in A\wedge x\notin B) \} \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \{x\mid ((x\in A\wedge x\in B) \vee x\in A) \wedge ((x\in A\wedge x\in B) \vee x\notin B) \} \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \{x\mid ((x\in A\vee x\in A)\wedge (x\in A\vee x\in B)) \wedge ((x\in A\vee x\notin B) \wedge (x\in B\vee x\notin B) \} \\
&= \{x\mid (x\in A\wedge (x\in A\vee x\in B)) \wedge (x\in A\vee x\notin B) \} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge ((x\in A\vee x\in B) \wedge (x\in A\vee x\notin B)) \} \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=} \{x\mid x\in A\wedge (x\in A\vee (x\in B \wedge x\notin B)) \} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A\wedge x\in A \} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A \} \\
&= A
\end{alignat}

---

A much simpler option, to the aim of the OP, is to use this other:

**Lemma 2**. If $\mathcal{P}$, $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are propositions, then:

$$\mathcal{P}\wedge (\mathcal{Q}\vee \mathcal{R})= (\mathcal{P}\wedge \mathcal{Q})\vee (\mathcal{P}\wedge \mathcal{R}) \tag 2$$

*Proof*. By showing that the truth tables of the LHS and RHS of $(2)$ are equal for the same entries of $\mathcal{P}$, $\mathcal{Q}$ and $\mathcal{R}$. $\space\Box$

By the Lemma 2:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(A \cap B) \cup(A\cap B') &= \{x\mid (x\in A\wedge x\in B) \vee (x\in A\wedge x\notin B) \} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A \wedge (x\in B\vee x\notin B) \} \\
&= \{x\mid x\in A \} \\
&= A
\end{alignat}